# Bindings in UIViewControllerRepresentable with Storyboard

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I have a UIViewControllerRepresentable with a UIStoryboard. How do I pass my @ObservedObject to the ViewController? It's currently not initialised, and I can't pass it to "as! ARView(model: model)"

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = ARView
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ARView {
        UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(identifier: "Main") as! ARView
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ARViewContainer.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ARViewContainer>) { }
    
}

class ARView: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
    
    // MARK: Object model
    
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    
    // MARK: - Initalisation
    
    init(model: Model) {
        self.model = model
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to use `@ObservableObject` inside a `UIViewController`. The property wrapper isn't doing you any good like it would inside a `View`, triggering updates.

An `@ObservableObject` can't be an `Optional`, but since it no longer has to have the property wrapper, you *can* make it an `Optional`. Obviously, you'll have to unwrap when it needs to be used.

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = ARView
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(identifier: "Main") as! ARView
        vc.model = model
        return vc
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ARViewContainer.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ARViewContainer>) {
    }
        
}

class ARView: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
    var model: Model?
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think the problem for me was not realising that I could initialise the property with "vc.model" but it all makes sense now!